# how can prevent popup close when mouse clicked outsie of popop

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF When we clicked on Toggle button then popup open properly but when we clicked on outside of popup then popup is auto closed. how to prevent this.

when we clicked on outside of popup then the popup should not be closed.

Code:

```
<ToggleButton Name="TglBtn" Content="Document" /> 
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TglBtn}" StaysOpen="False"   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=popupDocshow}" x:Name="pop1"> 
  <TextBlock Text="Documents" Background="Blue"/> 
</Popup>
```

Comment: Can please post ur popup code

Comment: Make it a dedicated modal window, rather than a popup if you want to force an action to close it (like a button being pressed).

Comment: <ToggleButton Name="TglBtn"    Content="Document" />
            <Popup  IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TglBtn}" StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=popupDocshow}" x:Name="pop1" >
             <TextBlock Text="Documents" Background="Blue"/>
            </Popup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PopupTest.StaysOpen = true` this is what you are missing.

```
<Popup x:Name="PopupTest" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Wow, that was easy!"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Popup>

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PopupTest.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Mouse;
    PopupTest.StaysOpen = true;
    PopupTest.Height = 1000;
    PopupTest.Width = 500;
    PopupTest.IsOpen = true;       
}
```

this is the popup i checked on